# (ListFragment) What exactly should the OnItemClickListener attach to?

Tags: android, android-listfragment, onitemclicklistener, event-listener

I'm currently writing an app that has a main Activity with a fragment-container (programmatically added when in portrait view, and two Fragment views created from the XML layout when in landscape view) and a ListFragment fragment that has a List View with a bunch of items (put into the view via an Adapter). The main Activity implements the ListFragment's callback interface.

I'm having trouble getting the ListFragment's `onListItemClick()` to work. From reading and working through other examples online, it seems like that should be enough, but it doesn't work. I've tried adding event listeners to both the ListView and the individual list items, but neither seem to work; actually, I'm not sure where those should even go. I've tried putting them in both `onCreateView()` and 'onActivityCreated()`. I've also made sure that the Views are set with`android:clickable = "true"` in the XML files, and that no other View objects were stealing focus from the ListView items.

What am I missing here?

ListFragment Activity:

```
public class IdeaListFragment extends ListFragment {    
    /** various methods and variables **/
  @Override
    // Makes sure the container Activity has implemented the callback interface
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try {
            mCallback = (OnIdeaSelectedListener) context;
        } catch(ClassCastException cce) {
            Log.e(TAG, "OnIdeaSelectedListener not implemented: ", cce);
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnIdeaSelectedListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int pos, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, pos, id);
        mCallback.onIdeaSelected(mBucket.getIdeaAt(pos));
        getListView().setItemChecked(pos, true);
    }
}
```

Main Activity:

```
public class MainIdeasListViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements IdeaListFragment.OnIdeaSelectedListener,
    IdeaDetailFragment.OnIdeaUpdatedListener {
    /** various methods and variables **/
    public void onIdeaSelected(IdeaItem idea) {
    IdeaDetailFragment ideaDetailFrag = (IdeaDetailFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.idea_detail_fragment);

    if(ideaDetailFrag != null)
        ideaDetailFrag.newInstance(idea);
    else {
        IdeaDetailFragment newDetailFrag = new IdeaDetailFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(UUIDKEY, idea.getUUID().toString());
        newDetailFrag.setArguments(args);
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
                                            .beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newDetailFrag);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

listitem XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:clickable = "true"
              android:longClickable = "true"
              android:orientation = "vertical"
              android:layout_width = "match_parent"
              android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
              android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:orientation = "horizontal"
        style = "@style/ListItem">

        <ImageView
            android:id = "@id/icon_idea_item_status"
            android:contentDescription = ""
            style = "@style/ListMainIcon" />

        <LinearLayout style = "@style/ListItemBody">
            <TextView
                android:id = "@id/text_idea_title"
                style = "@style/ListItemBodyTitle" />

            <TextView
                android:id = "@id/text_idea_description"
                style = "@style/ListItemBodySubtitle"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id = "@id/icon_idea_item_submenu"
            android:focusableInTouchMode = "true"
            android:contentDescription = "@string/list_idea_submenu"
            style = "@style/ListSubmenuIcon"
            android:clickable = "true"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <View style = "@style/divider" />

</LinearLayout>
```

ListView fragment XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools = "http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:orientation = "vertical"
              android:layout_width = "match_parent"
              android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
              tools:context = ".IdeaListFragment"
              style = "@style/AppMain">

    <ListView
        android:id = "@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:clickable = "true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Where/how you create `mCallback` ?

Comment: In `onAttach()`; I pasted that part of the code into the main post.

Comment: Post your fragment xml file

Comment: Sure thing. Did you notice something I missed?

Comment: Thats strange, your code looks ok. Try to add `android:focusable="false"` to all item child views (in item.xml) and remove `android:clickable = "true"` from the List and ImageView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
remove android:clickable = "true" from listview fragment XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools = "http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:orientation = "vertical"
              android:layout_width = "match_parent"
              android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
              tools:context = ".IdeaListFragment"
              style = "@style/AppMain">

    <ListView
        android:id = "@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        />
</LinearLayout>




Add  focusable and clickable false to each child item in listitem XML

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

              android:orientation = "vertical"
              android:layout_width = "match_parent"
              android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
              android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:orientation = "horizontal"
        style = "@style/ListItem"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="false">

        <ImageView
            android:id = "@id/icon_idea_item_status"
            android:contentDescription = ""
            style = "@style/ListMainIcon" 
            android:focusable="false"
            android:clickable="false"/>

        <LinearLayout style = "@style/ListItemBody"
         android:focusable="false"
         android:clickable="false">
            <TextView
                android:id = "@id/text_idea_title"
                style = "@style/ListItemBodyTitle" 
                 android:focusable="false"
                  android:clickable="false"/>

            <TextView
                android:id = "@id/text_idea_description"
                style = "@style/ListItemBodySubtitle"
                 android:focusable="false"
                   android:clickable="false"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id = "@id/icon_idea_item_submenu"
            android:focusableInTouchMode = "true"
            android:contentDescription = "@string/list_idea_submenu"
            style = "@style/ListSubmenuIcon"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:clickable="false"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <View style = "@style/divider" 
    android:focusable="false"
     android:clickable="false"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What if I need that ImageView in the listitem.xml to be clickable?

Comment: click on imageview must be handled in your custom adapter class

Comment: Ahh, hey, that worked! Thanks much! Why do you have to do all that? I thought it was only other buttons that stole the View focus from the ListView item, but apparently it's all child views?